# Image Code Execution

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a php image upload script that permits jpg, jpeg, png, and gif files to upload to another directory. Of course, I check the mime/type and the file extension in the upload script, but a smart hacker can easily get around those.

I have a vague understanding that somehow you can embed executable code into these image files. Googling for over an hour, I have yet to find a way to execute code inside the images on a standard Godaddy apache configuration. All I found was that if the file type is something like test.php.jpg, then the code might execute. So, I changed my htaccess file for that particular upload folder to

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^([0-9]*)[.](jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ /error.php?
```

My question is if this is enough or is it still vulnerable? If so, do you have any ideas on how to secure the file to only be a pure image with not executable code.

Comment: Restricting the uploaded image from having any execute permissions (chmod a-x) may help.

Comment: Do you know if you can do this on godaddy shared hosting? *googles*

Comment: all you'd be doing with that is completely disabling being able to serve ANY images from your server. a .jpg file with some executable code in it is not dangerous by itself - unless you take the steps to tell Apache (and the underlying OS) that a .jpg should be treated as a .exe... and even then, it'd just crash, because a.jpg with executable code in it is not the same as having a .exe

Comment: As a side note: the issue with having something named test.php.jpg that executes is usually because of 'multiviews' being enabled in apache.  This is built in language support - so if a user typed in /myscript.php - and they were english, it would search for myscript.php.en - or if it was a locale of spanish, it would attempt to run myscript.php.es.  So, in the example you gave, that's simply a PHP script that is saying it is of language 'jpg.'  Just background info. :)

Comment: @MarcB what do you mean I would disable any images being served with that code? ArronSaray- That's interesting.